# Using If conditions in Parent/child Class in Python

Tags: python, class, if-statement, constructor, parent-child

***#I have a parent class vehicle and two child class: Bus and Cars. I am trying to put a condition where if Vehicle is Bus, it should return white color while if class in Cars, it should return Red, NOTE: I don't wan specify default color under child class***

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, name, mileage):
        self.name = name
        self.mileage = mileage

    def color(self):
        if Vehicle == Cars:
            return "Red"
        else:
            return "White"


class Bus(Vehicle):
    pass

class Cars(Vehicle):
    pass


School_bus = Bus("School Volvo", 12)
Racing_Car1 = Cars("Audi", 10)
Racing_Car2 = Cars("BMW", 5)


print("The Bus has Color:", School_bus.color())
print("The car has color:", Racing_Car2.color())
```

Comment: What should happen if the name is neither `Audi` nor `BMW`? What should happen if the argument is neither a `Cars` or a `Bus`?

Comment: lets say if name is neither audi or bmw in cars, we can give default color as white.
Also, I dont want to include color in --init-- method of class "Vehicle"

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the argument is a `Cars` with `isinstance()`, and if not, test if it has a `color` attribute with `hasattr()`:

```
def get_color(vehicle):
  if isinstance(vehicle, Cars):
    if vehicle.Name == "Audi":
      return "Black"
    return "White"

  if hasattr(vehicle, "color"):
    return vehicle.color

  return "<UNKNOWN>"
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
class Vehicle:
    def __init__(self, name, tyre, price, color = ""):
        self.name = name
        self.tyre = tyre
        self.price = price
        self.color = color

class Bus(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, name, tyre, price, color = ""):
        if color == "":
            color = "Blue"
        super(Bus, self).__init__(name, tyre, price, color)

class Cars(Vehicle):
    def __init__(self, name, tyre, price, color = ""):
        if color == "":
            if name == "BMW":
                color = "White"
            if name == "Audi":
                color = "Black"
        super(Cars, self).__init__(name, tyre, price, color)

School_bus = Bus("Volvo", "TVS", 1200)
Racing_Car1 = Cars("Audi", "MRF", 5000)
Racing_Car2 = Cars("BMW", "MRF", 3000)

print(School_bus.name, "and its color is:", School_bus.color)
print(Racing_Car2.name, "and its color is:", Racing_Car2.color)
```

It sets the Color at the creation of an Object. You don't need to check it later.

Comment: Thanks for the code, can we do this without including 'color' in vehicle class?

Comment: You don't need to specify the color in the `Vehicle` Class because it is a named parameter with a default value (`= ""`). You can still Create a Object with `vehicle1 = Vehicle("name", "tyre", 123)`. I think it is more readable with the `color` in the Parent Class, because a `Vehicle` can also have a `color` and you dont have multiple variables for the same thing. But you can change the `color` variable to be part of `Bus` or `Cars`.